# Can functions in MVC interact across controllers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, typescript

I am new to MVC and Angular.

I have two controllers and two associated views, exampleview1.cshtml/ts and exampleview2.cshmtl/ts.

In exampleview1.cshtml I have a button that uses the Angular directive 'ng-click' to call a function from exampleview1.ts.

In exampleview2.cshmtl I have a paragraph that has some text. This paragraph is enclosed in a div that uses the 'ng-if' directive to call a function from exampleview2.ts that initially hides the div. This is done using jQuery's .hide() method.

I want the button in exampleview1 to be tied to the text from exampleview2. When this particular button is clicked it should set the text in exampleview2 to be visible (maybe using jQuery's .toggle() or .show() methods).

How do I set it up so that when the button is clicked, it calls the events tied to it as normal, but also tells the function in exampleview2.ts to toggle from .hide() to .show()? At the moment the function tied to the 'ng-if' directive looks like the following:

```
 viewScope.testingText = function () {
            $('#divcontainstext').hide();
            return true;
        };
```

So at the moment it's forced to be hidden but I'm not sure will this function need to be changed to accommodate a .show() line etc. I'm not sure how to go about tying these functions together.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of **ng-show** directive in example2.html which has a scope value attached to it which tells it either true or false.

And **broadcast** an event from inside the example1.html on click so that when this event is **listened** inside example2.html, it changes the  ng-show's scope var value.

**example1.html**

```
   <button ng-click="change()">Click </button>

   app.controller('example1Ctrl,function($rootScope,$scope){
   $scope,change=function(){
      $rootScope.broadcast('visibleStatus','true');
   }
 }
```

**example2.html:**

```
    <div ng-show="visible">//some contents that needs to be hidden/shown
    </div>

    app.controller('example2Ctrl',function($rootScope,$scope){
        $scope.visible=false;
        $rootScope.$on('visibleStatus',function(event,data){
             $scope.visible=data;
        }
    }
```

This might not be the exact code to be copied and run, but try this methodology and may be use your own related code.